# Grey bar underneath TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

Currently I'm programming an Application which shows data from a file in an TableLayoutPanel. But somehow the more rows it shows the bigger an grey bar at the end of the TableLayoutPanel gets.

This shows an example of the grey bar. I think its because of the cell border, but what can I do? The CellBorderStyle is on Single.

[image]

edit: I changed the Style to Inset and its like I have 5 or more very small rows underneath. Here is the code which changes the TableLayoutPanel:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Name = "Header";
label.Text = cont;
if (row == 0)
{
   label.Font = new Font(label.Font.FontFamily, 12);
   label.Font = new Font(label.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}
tlP_Head.RowCount++;
tlP_Head.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
tlP_Head.Controls.Add(label, col, row);
```

This is what it looks with Cellstyle Inset:

[image]

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code that sets the rows' properties. It surely looks as if the TLP is simply too large for the rows you add.

Comment: try to change `tlP_Head.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());`  to `tlP_Head.RowStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0.24));` is there any change?

Comment: TAW: There is no other code wich changes something at the TableLayoutPanel. I did it with this ObjectInspector.
jonathana: I'll try it when I can ;)

Comment: Do not use `TableLayoutPanel` for showing data, `TableLayoutPanel` designed for layout other controls. Instead use `DataGridView` for data.

Comment: @Fabio: But that is what he does! Labels are controls after all!

Comment: Stuff you do in the designer is also code (in the designer.cs file). You don't even show us the what, loop(s) where col and row come from..

Comment: Would it be better to use DataGridView or TLP?
I do not change anything at the designer.cs^^
Its an own method, so row and col are parameters

Comment: @TaW - correct. But my point was that OP need explicitly create/provide all controls for `TableLayoutPanel`, where `DataGridView` will create them automatically for collection of data

Comment: Yes, from the looks it is a typical DGV job.

Comment: You can set the BackColor = Color.Transparent